# Remove leading timestamp (minutes) from PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, ansi-escape, powershell-ise

I am using PowerShell ISE and when I get an error, this weird timestamp is leading the error message and this is starting to get annoying.

Command:

```
PS C:\Users\serhat> terraform plan -var="ENVIRONMENT=Test" -var="POSTFIX=test" -var="PROJECT=common"
```

Output:

```
terraform : [31mâ•·[0m[0m
At line:1 char:1
+ terraform plan -var="ENVIRONMENT=Test" -var="POSTFIX=test" -var="PROJ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ([31mâ•·[0m[0m:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

[31mâ”‚[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mNo configuration files[0m
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m[0mPlan requires configuration to be present. Planning without a configuration
[31mâ”‚[0m [0mwould mark everything for destruction, which is normally not what is
[31mâ”‚[0m [0mdesired. If you would like to destroy everything, run plan with the
[31mâ”‚[0m [0m-destroy option. Otherwise, create a Terraform configuration file (.tf
[31mâ”‚[0m [0mfile) and try again.
[31mâ•µ[0m[0m
```

How do prevent this weird timestamp `[31mâ”‚[0m [0m[1m[31m` from appearing in all my ouputs?

PS: I am seeking for a permanent solution as I don't want to run a regex everytime I run a script.

Comment: Those aren't time stamps. They're ANSI terminal escape codes for setting text attributes like `red`,`bold`,`normal` etc. I've no idea why they should be showing up on your system, but look at the ISE configuration options.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I think you are correct. They are color codes but looking like a timestamp. Setting terraform's variable`TF_CLI_ARGS="-no-color"` in computer's environment variables seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 6+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: Amazing side-note @mklement0 . Thank you for that! I will try to switch to VS Code then.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Serhat, but please note that if you're using _Windows PowerShell_ you'll need the latest and last version, v5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable Terraform's colored output, pass the [`-no-color`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/plan#no-color) switch for a single command. One can also set up an environment variable [`TF_CLI_ARGS="-no-color"`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables#tf_cli_args-and-tf_cli_args_name) in case a global supression is needed.

Comment: Setting `TF_CLI_ARGS="-no-color"` in computer's environment variables seems to have resolved the issue permanently without specifying `-no-color` in every command. Thank you! @vonPryz